# Ceaser Cipher-Python, using large numbers for shifts

Tags: python

I need help with my ceaser cipher code. I need to be able to shift/decrypt a letter even when the shift value is greater than 122. My code only works for shift values that are less than 22. The code fails when the user specifies an input for the shifter that is greater than 122 How can I do this? For a with shifter 123 the output should be r

```
k = int(raw_input("Please enter a value for k: ")) #Shifter number
original = raw_input("plaintext:  ") #Message user wants ciphered
original_as_array = list(original) ##I am turning the input into an array

for i in range(0,len(original)): ##Now seperating each character to add k
    char = original_as_array[i]
    charint = ord(char)

    if charint >= 65 and charint <=90:
        cipher_int = ((charint-65 + k) % 26)+65
        code_char = chr(cipher_int)
        print code_char,

    elif charint >= 97 and charint <=122:
        cipher_int = ((charint-97 + k) % 26)+97
        code_char = chr(cipher_int)
        print code_char,


    else:
        print char,
```

Comment: Is this how the code looks exactly in your editor? If yes, `if` is not part of the for loop

Comment: no sorry. I will fix it

Comment: Please do that and also explain for what input your code fails, I dont see any problem with your code.

Comment: Can you please provide expected output for a sample data when the input is greater than 122?

Comment: Whoops, you forgot to tell us. What is the `k` to achieve that?

Comment: @njkj I dont think for `a`, the output should be `r`, it should be `t` only. `(123 % 26) + 97` is `t` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Caesar Cipher

#Function that reads and writes data to the file, and calls the encryption and decryption methods.
#It isolates the key and choice of the user, and then calls the appropriate function.
def isolate():
    #Open input file in read mode
    fin = open('Input3.txt', 'r')
    #Open output file in write mode
    fout = open('Out1.txt', 'w')
    #Create a list that holds each line of the file as an element of the list
    container = fin.readlines()

    #For loop that goes through each line of the file (contianed in list) and isolates the choice and key of the user
    #Then it removes the key and choice from the split input list and calls the appropriate method.
    for i in container:
        # List of words, with whitespace and trailing '\n' removed
        words = i.split()

        # Interpret and remove the last two words
        key = int(words[len(words) - 1])
        choice = words[len(words) - 2]
        words.remove(str(key))
        words.remove(choice)

        # Re-join the words of the message. The message may differ from the original if there is consecutive whitespace.
        message = ' '.join(words)
        message = message.upper()

        # Encrypt or decrypt to fout
        if choice == 'e':

            fout.write(encrypt(message, key) + '\n')

        else:
            fout.write(decrypt(message, key) + '\n')

    #Close the file to make sure data is written properly to the file.
    fout.close()

#Encryption method, which takes two parameters, the users message and key, and returns the newly encrypted message.
def encrypt(message, key):
    #Empty string that will contain the encrypted message.
    encrypted_message = ""
    #Alphabet string, which contains all the letters of the alphabet at their index locations.
    alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    #For loop that goes through each character of the users message and, if a space, adds it straight to the encrypted message or encrypts it through modular division.
    for i in message:
        #If the character is a space, add it to the final message.
        if i == ' ':
            #Concatenate the space to the final message
            encrypted_message += ' '
        #If the character is not a space, determine the final locatin out of index range, % by 26 and re-add the character at this index to the encrypted_message.
        else:
            #Determine the final location of the character (out of index range)
            location = key + alpha.index(i)
            #% this location by 26 to determine the location within the proper index.
            location %= 26
            #Finally, concatenate the letter at this location to the final message.
            encrypted_message += alpha[location]

    #When the function is called, have it return the final encrypted message.
    return encrypted_message


#Decryption method that takes two parameters, the users message and key
def decrypt(message, key):
    #Create a string that reverses the alphabet, since we are moving backwards when we decrypt.
    reverse_alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[::-1]
    decrypted_message = ""

    #For loop that runs through each element of the users message and, if space,  adds it to the message, or encrypts using % division, then concatenates to final message.
    for i in message:
        if i == ' ':
            decrypted_message += ' '
        else:
            #Determine the final location out of index range of the encrypted character
            location = key + reverse_alpha.index(i)
            #% this position by 26 to determine the index location in range of the letter.
            location %= 26
            #Finally, add the letter at this location to the decrypted message.
            decrypted_message += reverse_alpha[location]

    #Converts the decrypted message into lowercase form.
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.lower()

    return decrypted_message

#Call the function isolate5(), which initiates the program.
isolate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because you didn't specify a condition when `ord(char)` > 122. Instead, you threw it to the else clause.

You can just cut the part `<= 122`:

```
for k in range(20):
    for i in range(0,len(original)): ##Now seperating each character to add k
        char = original[i]
        charint = ord(char)

        if charint >= 65 and charint <=90:
            cipher_int = ((charint-65 + k) % 26)+65
            code_char = chr(cipher_int)
            print code_char,

        elif charint >= 97:
            cipher_int = ((charint-97 + k) % 26)+97
            code_char = chr(cipher_int)
            print code_char,


        else:
            print char,
```

With `k` set to 18, this will produce `r`. If this solution wasn't what you meant, feel free to coment below!

Comment: I dont think the program has any problem in the logic but in his understanding.

Comment: Actually, i don't really understand his understanding either.

Comment: Whoops, was using tabs instead of spaces. Fixed